# Python syntax detail when multiplying a tuple

Tags: python

I tried to create a tuple containing two float number. `(4.0, 4.0)`, for example. However, as the two floats was the same, I wrote `4.0, * 2`.

What I wanted to do can be written: `(4.0,) * 2`. In Python, multiply a tuple by an integer says to Python to concatenate this number of times the tuple with itself. So `(4.0,) * 2 = (4.0,) + (4.0,) = (4.0, 4.0)`. OK.

What I did not want to do is `4.0 * 2` (without the comma). Indeed, this will multiply the float `4.0` itself by `2`: `4.0 * 2 = 8.0`. OK.

But none of these comportments happened. Instead of `8.0` or `(4.0, 4.0)`, I got a

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I am pretty surprized by this answer. How this syntax can lead to an iteration of `2` (which is the sole integer of this expression)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is matter of precedence, mixed with a wrong operator interpretation.

`*` (a multiplication) has a higher precedence than `,`: `4.0, 4.0 * 2 = 4.0, (4.0 * 2) = (4.0, 8.0)`. In my expression, it cannot be understood as this, because nothing can be multiplyed by two: `4.0, <nothing> * 2`. As a multiplication is a binary operator, it must have a value to the left, which must be `4.0,` itself.

This is quite true… for the binary `*` operator. However, Python has a unary `*` operator, whose precedence is also higher than `,`. This unary operator is used to expand an iterable in-place. This is often seen when we define or call a function with a variable number of arguments:

```
def min(first, *others): ...
data = tuple(4, 5, 6, 7)
min(*data)
```

It is this operator that is used in my expression. Python interprets `4.0, * 2` as `4.0, (*2)`, which says “a tuple, containing `4.0` as first element, followed by all elements contained in `2`”. Effectively, an integer is not iterable, and Python complains about it.

As proof, we can compute this expression, which actually gives an iterable to the `*` unary operator:

```
>>> 4.0 , * ( 5.0 , 6.0 )  # equivalent of  (4.0, (*(5.0, 6.0)))
(4.0, 5.0, 6.0)
```